# Finding a download url, or way to automatically trigger button click event

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

ON this page: https://razzball.com/mlbhittingstats/ , there is an option to get the CSV data of the page as a download. What I am wondering, is if there is a way to trigger this programatically..

I figure that button has to be pointing towards some url or some function and there is a way to call it. Otherwise I feel like I would have to use a webdriver and somehow click the button. Is this possible? Or do I have to use a headless, automated browser

Comment: [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) can find and click buttons

Comment: @JacobIRR so you'd have to use a headless driver then?

Comment: [Selenium can be headless or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing)

Answer (score 0):

This "Export to CSV" feature is entirely javascript-based/client-side - the table is a implemented using the [jQuery tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html) library.

In order to do the "export" you would need a way to execute JavaScript in the context of the rendered page - arguably the easiest way to do it would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simply click the button, but you can also do trigger the ["export to csv" programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23298952/771848) which allow for options like [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash).

If you go "selenium route", make sure to allow CSV files to be downloaded automatically:

- [Firefox + Selenium WebDriver and download a csv file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18759762/771848)
- [Chrome Web Driver download files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23530399/771848)

---

Another alternative idea would probably be to do the CSV exporting on your own - for instance, using `pandas` library and its [`read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to HTML parse the table and [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to dump a DataFrame into CSV.